# All my browsers (Chrome, IE, Edge, Opera and Firefox) download a Office-files instead of open it

Tags: sharepoint-online, download

First of all I apologize for my bad English.

If a user opens for example an xlsx file he downloads it. From now on it is no longer connected to the uploaded xlsx file and changes will not saved. That's exactly not what I want my browsers to do. The file should be opened on the client with Excel and still connected to the file which was uploaded on the server. I've tested it with all my installed browsers: IE, Edge, Chrome, Firefox and Opera and it's every time the same problem.

I've done some research and didn't find any solution which works for me. The OpenInClient feature is activated. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: What is the version of Office client are you using? It seems that SharePoint has failed to identify the client to open the files, so that they get downloaded directly.

Comment: You're English is fine mate - hope you solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things you can check:

1. Try switching to “Open in the browser” and disable download in Library Settings and see if you can get the documents to open in browser.
2. Switch to another machine and see if you can reproduce this issue.
3. Open the Word client application and try connecting to the SharePoint library by entering the URL in the address bar. See if you can get the connection to work.

   [image]
4. [Do a repair to the Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/repair-an-office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b) client on your machine if necessary.

Comment: Hey, sry for my laaate answer and many thanks for your help. I've tried all those steps, but nothing really worked. Sharepoint just wasn't able to identify the client. So we decided to completely reset the computer which solved the problem.